# Существует ли cli приложение для endpoint security checlpoint vpn на Mac m1?

Tags: консоль, macos, vpn, поиск-программ, homebrew

На глаза попадалась только десктопная версия с гуи, а хочется терминальную(
Видел гайды на линуксовую, но на мак отсутствует

Answer (score 0):

Нашел скрипт в GitHub, который запускает либо останавливает уже запущенный Endpoint Security VPN: https://gist.github.com/bubenkoff/4043130

Comment: а что насчёт самостоятельного запуска без приложения?
просто к сервису обращаться, без гуишки